# Json.net serialising to a specific json format without property names

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to write a custom implementation for tinymce spellchecker. I need a JSON object of the format to be returned from my ashx page

```
{
  "words": {
     "misspelled1": ["suggestion1", "suggestion2"],
     "misspelled2": ["suggestion1", "suggestion2"]
  }
}
```

Where misspelled1 and 2 are misspelled words and their respective suggestions, words is the id so a practical example would be

```
{words:{
"wod":["wood","wooden"],
"tak":["take","taken"]}
}
```

I have tried this

```
public class incorrectWords
{
    public string word { get; set; }
    public string[] suggestions { get; set; }

}

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            words= new List<incorrectWords>()
                    {
                        new words {word="wod",suggestions = new string[]{ "wood","wooden" } },
                        new words  {word="tak",suggestions= new string[]{ "talk","take" } }
        }
        });

context.Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));

    }
```

However that adds the property names words and suggestion and I end up with the following which is not what I need.

```
"{\"words\":[{\"word\":\"wod\",\"suggestions\":[\"wood\",\"wooden\"]},{\"word\":\"tak\",\"suggestions\":[\"talk\",\"take\"]}]}"
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers. Some posts seem to indicate I will need a custom converter, I am wondering if it is a simple matter of designing the incorrectWords class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should map your list to dictionary if you want to have key-value pairs in JSON.
Here is a modified version of your code, which works:

```
var words = new List<incorrectWords>() {
            new incorrectWords() {word="wod",suggestions = new string[]{ "wood","wooden" } },
            new incorrectWords() {word="tak",suggestions= new string[]{ "talk","take" } }
};

var dic = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
words.ForEach(word =>
{
    dic.Add(word.word, word.suggestions);
});

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
    words = dic
});

context.Response.Write(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));
```

Comment: Nicely played. Thanks for that, might just use a dictionary and ditch the class completely